# Showing Date range in d3.js graph axis

Tags: d3.js, graph

Right now for showing time on a line chart, I'm doing:

```
d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom').ticks(numTicks, 1)
          .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%a %d'))
```

which shows me dates like: Tue 12 on x-axis.

However, now I want to show the date range (something like: Tue 12-Tue 19) on the axis, but not getting how to do this.

Comment: You can't do this with a time scale. You would need to use an ordinal scale where the label is given as a range explicitly.

Comment: I am not sure if this can be done by a time scale. Maybe it is possible to get the max (and min) value with d3.max(data, function(d) {} ); After that put the min value at the left side and the max value at the right side of your axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had to do something like this:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom').ticks(numTicks, 1)
          .tickFormat(function(d,i) {return dateRanges[i]}).tickSize(6).tickPadding(8);
```

where dateRanges = an array containing all the dateRange string